WordPress .htaccess ignored from local apache server
I have a local WordPress setup where I want to develop plugins and themes. I've noticed that the url will include always index.php. I've tried to modify the permalink structure but nothing changed. At the moment my .htaccess file looks like this
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

I've installed recently a new version of php using MacPorts and I'm not sure if mod_rewrite is working correctly. How I can make things working correctly and have http://localhost:5000/pagename instead of http://localhost:5000/index.php/pagename?

Remove the IfModule wrappers, then you should get an error, if mod_rewrite is not enabled. If that's not the case, and still nothing happens, check on the AccessFileName directive in the Apache config, to make sure it is set to parse .htaccess files to begin with. And if that is also the case and it is still not working, check on AllowOverride, it needs to include at least FileInfo.

Where I can find the apache config file? Since I've installed php 8.3 using MacPorts, does this operation installed a new version of apache? The problem will occur when I run the embedded php server

"The problem will occur when I run the embedded php server" - wait, are you talking about https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php here? That is only a very basic HTTP server, and doesn't support .htaccess.

At the moment I don't have any other webserver installed form my needings the basic php server was good for testing, but need a better solution to be able to have the front-controller pattern working, any suggetsion?

MAMP is a "classic" low-effort-required way of setting up Apache & PHP & MySQL, https://www.mamp.info/en/mamp/mac/

if I'm not wrong macOS has an embedded apache server?
